# Not able to execute ASSP procedure in SSAS Drillthrough action SSAS 2012

Tags: ssas

I need to write a custom drillthrough in SSAS 2012 Multidimensional cube so I used ASSP GetCustomMDX function but I am un able to execute it :-

**CALL ASSP.GetDefaultDrillthroughMDX([Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount])**

throws below error :-
No cube specified. A cube must be specified for this command to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrvgr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a cube name before [Measures]. Try this, just put your cube name instead of *YourCubeName*:

```
CALL ASSP.GetDefaultDrillthroughMDX([YourCubeName].[Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount])
```